# Xamarin iOS Google Analytics UncaughtExceptions not reported

Tags: ios, xamarin, google-analytics

Im trying out version 3.17.0.0 Google Analytics for iOS Xamarin.iOS.

I see my screens and my exceptions in the google dashboard but NOT the uncaughtExceptions. The app crashes fine but the uncaught exception causing the crash is not seen in the dashboard. Below is my initialization code. Any ideas?

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    GTracker = Gai.SharedInstance.GetTracker(StringConstants.TRACKING_ID);

    Gai.SharedInstance.OptOut = false;

    // change for app release
    Gai.SharedInstance.Logger.SetLogLevel(LogLevel.Verbose); 

    Gai.SharedInstance.DispatchInterval = Convert.ToUInt16(StringConstants.GOOGLE_DISPATCH_INTERVAL);

    // Send uncaught exceptions (Crashes) to Google Analytics.
    Gai.SharedInstance.TrackUncaughtExceptions = true;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any other service like HockeyApp that is also trying to catch uncaught exceptions?

Comment: @SushiHangover Not possible once the app is published and in the hands of my users.

Comment: @xleon No other service present. Thnx...

Comment: @SushiHangover Im not sure I follow your meaning. My goal is to see the crash (uncaught Exceptions) in the Google Analytics dashboard. They are supposed to be reported by virtue of Gai.SharedInstance.TrackUncaughtExceptions = true; however they are not.

Comment: @SushiHangover. I saw the docs. Crashes and Exceptions are displayed together in the GA dashboard and my crashes do not appear.